# To decode following Solr query

Tags: search, solr, lucene, sap-commerce-cloud

In our hybris schema, we are using LowerCaseFilterFactory. Also, the name/description is of type "text". Hence, solr treats 'ConsTRUCTION' and 'construction' the same way.
However, if I search for (two differnt keywords combined) toysChildren, then I get many results. However, toyschildren has no results.
So, wish to decode following code to understand what's letting it do that.

```
solrQuery-toysChildren:
        q=_query_:"\{\!multiMaxScore\+tie%3D0.0\}\(\(code_text\:toysChildren\^90.0\)\
        +OR\+\(keywords_text_en_mv\:toysChildren\^100.0\)\
        +OR\+\(name_text_en\:toysChildren\)\)\
        +OR\+\(\(keywords_text_en_mv\:toysChildren\~\^10.0\)\)\
        +OR\+\(\(keywords_text_en_mv\:toysChildren\*\^50.0\)\
        +OR\+\(name_text_en\:toysChildren\*\^45.0\)\)\
        +OR\+\(\(keywords_text_en_mv\:\"toysChildren\"\^100.0\)\
        +OR\+\(name_text_en\:\"toysChildren\"\~0.0\^90.0\)\)"
    &sort=score+desc&start=0&rows=100&facet.field=gender_string_mv
    &facet.field=price_gbp_string
    &facet.field=categoryPath_string_mv
    &facet.field=allCategories_string_mv
    &facet.field=excludeFromGiftFinder_boolean
    &facet.field=productVisible_boolean
    &facet.field=category_string_mv
    &facet.field=brand_string_mv
    &facet.field={!ex%3Dfk8}productType_string
    &facet.field=age_string_mv
    &facet=true
    &fq=productVisible_boolean:true
    &fq={!tag%3Dfk8}productType_string:(BUNDLE+OR+REGULAR+OR+ESD)
    &fq=(catalogId:"coreProductCatalog"+AND+catalogVersion:"Online")
    &facet.sort=count
    &facet.mincount=1
    &facet.limit=50
    &spellcheck=true
    &spellcheck.q=toysChildren&spellcheck.dictionary=en
    &spellcheck.collate=true
```

Note: Above is the solrQuery formed up in DefaultFacetSearchStrategy of type "SolrQuery". 
Query response is:

```
{responseHeader={status=0,QTime=18,params={facet.field=[gender_string_mv, price_gbp_string, categoryPath_string_mv, allCategories_string_mv, excludeFromGiftFinder_boolean, productVisible_boolean, category_string_mv, brand_string_mv, {!ex=fk8}productType_string, age_string_mv],spellcheck.dictionary=en,start=0,sort=score desc,fq=[productVisible_boolean:true, {!tag=fk8}productType_string:(BUNDLE OR REGULAR OR ESD), (catalogId:"coreProductCatalog" AND catalogVersion:"Online")],rows=100,version=2,q=_query_:"\{\!multiMaxScore\ tie=0.0\}\(\(code_text\:toysChildren\^90.0\)\ OR\ \(keywords_text_en_mv\:toysChildren\^100.0\)\ OR\ \(name_text_en\:toysChildren\)\)\ OR\ \(\(keywords_text_en_mv\:toysChildren\~\^10.0\)\)\ OR\ \(\(keywords_text_en_mv\:toysChildren\*\^50.0\)\ OR\ \(name_text_en\:toysChildren\*\^45.0\)\)\ OR\ \(\(keywords_text_en_mv\:\"toysChildren\"\^100.0\)\ OR\ \(name_text_en\:\"toysChildren\"\~0.0\^90.0\)\)",facet.limit=50,spellcheck.q=toysChildren,spellcheck=true,facet.mincount=1,facet=true,wt=javabin,facet.sort=count,spellcheck.collate=true}},response={numFound=3,start=0,docs=[SolrDocument{indexOperationId_long=79, id=coreProductCatalog/Online/100310, pk=8796107702273, catalogId=coreProductCatalog, catalogVersion=Online, allCategoryCodes_string=/SM06010425/SM060104/SM0601, price_gbp_string=£0 - £19.99, allCategories_string_mv=[SM06010425, SM0601, SM060104], category_string_mv=[SM06010425, SM0601, SM060104], rating_double=5.0, totalReviews_int=1, productType_string=REGULAR, excludeFromGiftFinder_boolean=true, pictureJson_string={"240":"https://image.smythstoys.com/picture/desktop/100310.jpg","220":"https://image.smythstoys.com/picture/tablet/100310.jpg","180":"https://image.smythstoys.com/picture/mobile/100310.jpg"}, gender_string_mv=[Female], autosuggest_en=[Sylvanian Families, Toys, Fashion & Dolls, Sylvanian Children's Bedroom Furniture], spellcheck_en=[Sylvanian Families, Toys, Fashion & Dolls, With 2 beech-style beds which can be stacked on top of each to make, Sylvanian Children's Bedroom Furniture], categoryName_text_en_mv=[Sylvanian Families, Toys, Fashion & Dolls], productVisible_boolean=true, url_en_string=/toys/fashion-and-dolls/sylvanian-families/sylvanian-children-s-bedroom-furniture/p/100310, pictureMap_string={min-width:1200=https://image.smythstoys.com/picture/desktop/100310.jpg, min-width:768=https://image.smythstoys.com/picture/tablet/100310.jpg, max-width:768=https://image.smythstoys.com/picture/mobile/100310.jpg}, priceValue_gbp_double=11.99, categoryNamePath_string_mv=[Toys, Toys > Fashion & Dolls, Toys > Fashion & Dolls > Sylvanian Families], categoryMetaTitle_string=SM06010425_Sylvanian Families: Awesome deals only at Smyths Toys UK, categoryMetaDescription_string=Sylvanian Families! Shop for an excellent range. Watch out for great offers at Smyths Toys UK, code_text=100310, description_text_en=With 2 beech-style beds which can be stacked on top of each to make, name_text_en=Sylvanian Children's Bedroom Furniture, name_sortable_en_sortabletext=Sylvanian Children's Bedroom Furniture, brand_string_mv=[Sylvanian], age_string_mv=[6 - 8 Years, 3 - 5 Years], categoryPath_string_mv=[/SM0601/SM060104, /SM0601, /SM0601/SM060104/SM06010425], customCategoryPath_string_mv=[/curl/toys/c/SM0601, /curl/toys/c/SM0601/curl/toys/fashion-and-dolls/c/SM060104, /curl/toys/c/SM0601/curl/toys/fashion-and-dolls/c/SM060104/curl/toys/fashion-and-dolls/sylvanian-families/c/SM06010425], ukBestsellerRating_en_int=999999, ukBestsellerRating_sortable_en_int=999999, pictureUrl_string=https://image.smythstoys.com/picture/desktop/100310.jpg, _version_=1577946952144781312}, SolrDocument{indexOperationId_long=79, id=coreProductCatalog/Online/100471, pk=8796108128257, catalogId=coreProductCatalog, catalogVersion=Online, allCategoryCodes_string=/SM06010326/SM060103/SM0601, price_gbp_string=£0 - £19.99, allCategories_string_mv=[SM06010326, SM0601, SM060103], category_string_mv=[SM06010326, SM0601, SM060103], rating_double=4.3, totalReviews_int=4, productType_string=REGULAR, excludeFromGiftFinder_boolean=false, pictureJson_string={"240":"https://image.smythstoys.com/picture/desktop/100471.jpg","220":"https://image.smythstoys.com/picture/tablet/100471.jpg","180":"https://image.smythstoys.com/picture/mobile/100471.jpg"}, gender_string_mv=[Male], autosuggest_en=[Vtech Infant, Toys, Pre-School & Electronic Learning, Toy Story Mr. Potato Head], spellcheck_en=[Vtech Infant, Toys, Pre-School & Electronic Learning, Includes lots of accessories and a special compartment for, Toy Story Mr. Potato Head], categoryName_text_en_mv=[Vtech Infant, Toys, Pre-School & Electronic Learning], productVisible_boolean=true, url_en_string=/toys/pre-school-and-electronic-learning/vtech-infant/toy-story-mr-potato-head/p/100471, pictureMap_string={min-width:1200=https://image.smythstoys.com/picture/desktop/100471.jpg, min-width:768=https://image.smythstoys.com/picture/tablet/100471.jpg, max-width:768=https://image.smythstoys.com/picture/mobile/100471.jpg}, priceValue_gbp_double=9.99, categoryNamePath_string_mv=[Toys, Toys > Pre-School & Electronic Learning, Toys > Pre-School & Electronic Learning > Vtech Infant], categoryMetaTitle_string=SM06010326_Vtech Infant: Awesome deals only at Smyths Toys UK, categoryMetaDescription_string=Vtech Infant! Shop for an excellent range. Watch out for great offers at Smyths Toys UK, code_text=100471, description_text_en=Includes lots of accessories and a special compartment for, name_text_en=Toy Story Mr. Potato Head, name_sortable_en_sortabletext=Toy Story Mr. Potato Head, brand_string_mv=[Toy Story], age_string_mv=[9 - 11 Years, 6 - 8 Years, 3 - 5 Years], categoryPath_string_mv=[/SM0601/SM060103/SM06010326, /SM0601/SM060103, /SM0601], customCategoryPath_string_mv=[/curl/toys/c/SM0601, /curl/toys/c/SM0601/curl/toys/pre-school-and-electronic-learning/c/SM060103, /curl/toys/c/SM0601/curl/toys/pre-school-and-electronic-learning/c/SM060103/curl/toys/pre-school-and-electronic-learning/vtech-infant/c/SM06010326], ukBestsellerRating_en_int=999999, ukBestsellerRating_sortable_en_int=999999, pictureUrl_string=https://image.smythstoys.com/picture/desktop/100471.jpg, _version_=1577946952157364224}, SolrDocument{indexOperationId_long=79, id=coreProductCatalog/Online/100838, pk=8796111962113, catalogId=coreProductCatalog, catalogVersion=Online, allCategoryCodes_string=/SM060307/SM0603, price_gbp_string=£0 - £19.99, allCategories_string_mv=[SM060307, SM0603], category_string_mv=[SM060307, SM0603], rating_double=0.0, productType_string=REGULAR, excludeFromGiftFinder_boolean=false, pictureJson_string={"240":"https://image.smythstoys.com/picture/desktop/100838.jpg","220":"https://image.smythstoys.com/picture/tablet/100838.jpg","180":"https://image.smythstoys.com/picture/mobile/100838.jpg"}, gender_string_mv=[Female], autosuggest_en=[Sports Equipment, Outdoor, 8oz Childrens Boxing Gloves], spellcheck_en=[Sports Equipment, Outdoor, 8oz childrens boxing gloves., 8oz Childrens Boxing Gloves], categoryName_text_en_mv=[Sports Equipment, Outdoor], productVisible_boolean=true, url_en_string=/outdoor/sports-equipment/8oz-childrens-boxing-gloves/p/100838, pictureMap_string={min-width:1200=https://image.smythstoys.com/picture/desktop/100838.jpg, min-width:768=https://image.smythstoys.com/picture/tablet/100838.jpg, max-width:768=https://image.smythstoys.com/picture/mobile/100838.jpg}, priceValue_gbp_double=4.99, categoryNamePath_string_mv=[Outdoor, Outdoor > Sports Equipment], categoryMetaTitle_string=SM060307_Sports Equipment: Awesome deals only at Smyths Toys UK, categoryMetaDescription_string=Sports Equipment! Shop for an excellent range. Watch out for great offers at Smyths Toys UK, code_text=100838, description_text_en=8oz childrens boxing gloves., name_text_en=8oz Childrens Boxing Gloves, name_sortable_en_sortabletext=8oz Childrens Boxing Gloves, age_string_mv=[9 - 11 Years, 6 - 8 Years], categoryPath_string_mv=[/SM0603/SM060307, /SM0603], customCategoryPath_string_mv=[/curl/outdoor/c/SM0603, /curl/outdoor/c/SM0603/curl/outdoor/sports-equipment/c/SM060307], ukBestsellerRating_en_int=999999, ukBestsellerRating_sortable_en_int=999999, pictureUrl_string=https://image.smythstoys.com/picture/desktop/100838.jpg, _version_=1577946952254881793}]},facet_counts={facet_queries={},facet_fields={gender_string_mv={Female=2,Male=1},price_gbp_string={£0 - £19.99=3},categoryPath_string_mv={/SM0601=2,/SM0601/SM060103=1,/SM0601/SM060103/SM06010326=1,/SM0601/SM060104=1,/SM0601/SM060104/SM06010425=1,/SM0603=1,/SM0603/SM060307=1},allCategories_string_mv={SM0601=2,SM060103=1,SM06010326=1,SM060104=1,SM06010425=1,SM0603=1,SM060307=1},excludeFromGiftFinder_boolean={false=2,true=1},productVisible_boolean={true=3},category_string_mv={SM0601=2,SM060103=1,SM06010326=1,SM060104=1,SM06010425=1,SM0603=1,SM060307=1},brand_string_mv={Sylvanian=1,Toy Story=1},productType_string={REGULAR=3},age_string_mv={6 - 8 Years=3,3 - 5 Years=2,9 - 11 Years=2}},facet_ranges={},facet_intervals={},facet_heatmaps={}},spellcheck={suggestions={},collations={}}}
```

Schema.xml - Some snippets: snippet 1-

```
<fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
            <analyzer>
                <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" ignoreCase="true" />
                <filter class="solr.ManagedStopFilterFactory" managed="en" />
                <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
                <filter class="solr.ManagedSynonymFilterFactory" managed="en" />
                <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"  preserveOriginal="1"
                    generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1"
                    catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" />
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" />
            </analyzer>
        </fieldType>
```

schema.xml Snippet 2:

```
<field name="text" type="textgen" indexed="true" stored="false" />
```

schema.xml Snippet 3:

```
<fieldType name="textgen" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
            <analyzer>
                <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
                <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
                <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                    generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1"
                    catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" preserveOriginal="1"/>
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
            </analyzer>
        </fieldType>
```

schema.xml Snippet 4:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
            <analyzer>
                <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
                <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
                <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                    generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1"
                    catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" preserveOriginal="1"/>
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
            </analyzer>
        </fieldType>
```

Comment: could you please show your schema.xml

Comment: I think there is no option to share a file. Its ~700 lines of code. What did you wanted to check in it? Will share the snippet related to that.

Comment: snippets related to field type of fields that you're querying against (e.g. keywords_text_en_mv, name_text_en, etc.)

Comment: No code related to keywords_text_en_mv or name_text_en specific added. However its type, i.e. text has some entries mentioned above (added snippet to the query).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you have different results because of `solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory` and the setting `splitOnCaseChange=1` which will break `toysChildren` into `toys` and `Children`. And in case of `toyschildren`, there is no case change, so you will only have token `toyschildren` and that's exactly what make the difference in your query results.

You have several choices depends on what is expected behaviour of your system. You could turn of this setting or completely remove `solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory` from fieldtype.

Comment: Thanks, that helped!

Comment: @sakshinarang, please upvote the answer as well, if it helps you.